# How to run an exe file to install an application?

Tags: powershell, exe

I have no expierence in PowerShell but I need to use it to install two different applications of which I have the exe file downloaded but am unable to run. What do I need to do in order to run them?

```
PS H:\> Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe
Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe : The term 'Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe' is not recognized
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is the error code and I have also tried the same code but with `.\` in front of the `Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe` file as suggested by the Microsoft Technet site linked in the comments.

The application is on a network drive, if that affects the result.

Comment: do at least a little research before posting your question. https://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiAv7GP5uTQAhXE_iwKHXU1Bb8QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.technet.microsoft.com%2Fwiki%2Fcontents%2Farticles%2F7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx&usg=AFQjCNGTA6tyoX3LeoIurhTwCkR2V7zNkw&sig2=VJUaNt4GXorzc1qxQrXfEA&cad=rja

Comment: Yeah whenever I attempt the suggestions given on the site it says that the "file is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..." etc and fails to run.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it contains no useful information. Keep in mind that nobody can read your mind nor see your screen. You need to spend some time on it and ask a good question.

Comment: If you have really tried the suggestions listed in the link 4c posted anda re still getting that error there would have to be something seriously wrong with your PowerShell install, but its much more likely you are making one of a number of possible syntax errors.  Can you show us a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem so that we can help get you working?

Comment: This time I took the liberty of doing it for you, but next time please [edit] your question if you need to provide additional information.

Comment: Is the file `Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe` actually present in the root folder of drive H:? Check by running `Get-ChildItem H:\ `. Also, do you get the exact same error if you run `.\Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$InstallerLoc = "LOCATION OF INSTALLER FILE"
$Switches = "SWITCHES TO PROVIDE TO INSTALLER"
$Installer = Start-Process -FilePath $InstallerLoc -ArgumentList $Switches -Wait -PassThru
Write-Host "The exit code is $($Installer.ExitCode)"
```

This script will install your software for you and wait until it's installed.
Then it will feedback your error code from the install.

If you are starting the script from the same location that the installer is in, you can use .\Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe otherwise you'll need to supply the fully qualified location of the installer.

To get the switches of the .exe if the .exe author has created the .exe to even have any, you can start a CMD window and put in the location of the .exe followed by a /?
For example: 
    Hide.me-Setup-1.2.8.exe /?
This sometimes shows a window with all the available switches that you can use, and their functions, if the installer just starts up as per normal, it's unlikely that it can be run silently.

If you don't have any switches to provide just leave the $Switches variable as ""